# Only 1 direct connection available at a time on Verizon Modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, modem

I have a Verizon ONT running through an 8-port switch, connecting it to all the ethernet ports in the apartment including the router. The router works fine until I plug my computer into the ethernet port in my bedroom, basically disconnecting the router from the internet and only giving internet access to my computer. My phone still shows a Wi-Fi connection but has no internet access. What can I do to allow the router to work while also providing a direct connection to the rest of the devices in the house?

Comment: plug your computer into the router ... otherwise talk to Verizon, don't be asking here

Comment: Yeah, I eventually found out that the Verizon ONT only supports a single direct connection which often goes to the router. Sorry if this type of question isn't normal here I just didn't really know where to ask.